# Pascal triangle using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, pascals-triangle

As the title says, I have a problem using list comprehension for creating the Pascal Triangle.

```
n = int(input())
a = []
a = [[1 if j > 0 and j < n-1 else a[i-1][j] + a[i-1][j-1] for j in range(i)] for i in range(n)]
print(*a, sep = '\n')
```

I get the following error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd6w5.png)

I don't understand where the index gets out of range and how I can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: this is straightfoward. `a` is an empty list, indexing an empty list will always produce an index error.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your attempt:

- You used the `if..else` operator in the opposite way: you'll want to produce 1 when the `if` condition is false, not when it is true.
- `j < n-1` is not the right limit condition. It should be `j < i`, and `j` should be in the range `range(i+1)`.
- Your comprehension never updates the `a` list, so the incremental update idea is not working. `a` remains empty until the whole comprehension has finished, while you'll want `a` to be incrementally updated at each increment of `i`. You can use `a :=` syntax to track the last row, while the list comprehension will use those rows to populate the triangle.

Here is your code updated with those remarks taken into account:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
a = [
    a := [
        a[j] + a[j-1] if 0 < j < i else 1
        for j in range(i+1)
    ]
    for i in range(n)
]

print(*a, sep = '\n')
```

Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To compute pascal triangle using list comprehension, you can use [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.factorial):

```py
from math import factorial as fct

rows = [[int(fct(n) / (fct(k) * fct(n - k))) for k in range(n + 1)] for n in range(5)]
print(*rows, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```py
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```